# Как обработать результат ajax запроса ??

Tags: ajax

Народ, имеется следующий вопрос.

Делаю запрос методом GET ПХП обработки сценария на вывод картинок. Искомые картинки на экран замечательно выводятся, но в исходный код страницы не прописываются. Эти картинки должны после удачного вывода обрабатываться плагином просмотра картинок, но т.к. исходного кода этих картинок на странице нет, то обработки не происходит.

Возможно ли получение ответа на запрос с прописыванием результата в исходный код страницы или есть какие то другие решения ??

Comment: покажите код

Answer (score 1):

Исходный код страницы - это html разметка которая изначально пришла в браузер, никакие динамические изменения в ней не отражаются и это сделано специально. Это нужно, что бы узнать, с какого кода стартует страница и была возможность сохранить ее изначальный вид. На основе этой разметки браузер строит DOM дерево, с которым и происходит вся работа.

Браузер работает только с DOM и во время построения определяет все свойства. Очевидно, плагин начинает работать, как только завершается построение DOM-дерева и выбирает оттуда картинки. На добавленные картинки после этого он внимания уже не обращает, так как отбор уже произошел.

Отсюда очевидно решение - разобраться в работе плагина по документации или коду и запустить его на выполнение уже после того, как прошел Ajax запрос.

Посмотрел какой-то prettyPhoto плагин, не знаю, этот ли, но сойдет как пример. Вот его код инициализации:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
>   $(document).ready(function(){
>     $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
>   });
> </script>
> ```

Как видно стартует он при готовности DOM дерева: $(document).ready(). А применяются изменения вызовом на каждой картинке функции prettyPhoto(), выбирая все ссылки с rel^='prettyPhoto'. Соответственно можно на каждую добавленную вновь картинку, а точнее в ссылку к этой картинке, выполнить код prettyPhoto() и получить нужный эффект.

Comment: Все разобрался. Вы правы, нужно было заново подгрузить плагин просмоторщика после Аякс запроса. Пока искал, оказалось, что с подобной проблемой аякса и jquery многие бились.

Answer (score 0):

Если они появляются динамически, значит есть в разметке коллекция узлов img, в каждом из которых в атрибуте src путь к картинке прописан. Селектором узлы вытащи и назначь например классы для обработки изображения, которые плагину нужны, не знаю какой уж плагин.

Comment: Наверное я неправильно объяснил.

Картинки из PHP выводятся уже в готовом для обработки виде 

(<a href='photo/collage/123.jpg' class='picPhoto' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery1]' title='dog'><img src='photo/collage/123.jpg' style='height:150px' alt=''/></a>)

По классу выборка делается с помощью плагина PrettyPhoto, то есть и класс, и все необходимые данные для последующей обработки имеются. Но они не прописаны в сам код страницы и плагин их не видит.

Comment: А когда проводишь инспектирование DOM страницы - картинки прописаны. То есть они как бы есть и их тут же нет.